# Convert Date String (Unix format) to Java Date using Gson API's

Tags: java, mongodb, gson

I am trying to convert json string date time into java date object using Gson Api's where my json string date is in unix format ("CreatedOn":"/Date(***1421909004755***+0530)/"). My java code for the same is

```
MyJsonbuilder.java is having code

GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
LogService book = gson.fromJson(dbDocument, LogService.class);
BasicDBObjectBuilder bs = new BasicDBObjectBuilder();
bs.append("CreatedOn", book.getCreatedOn());
```

where LogService.Java having getter and setter.

```
public Date getCreatedOn() {
    return CreatedOn;
}


public void setCreatedOn(Date CreatedOn) {

    this.CreatedOn = CreatedOn;

}
```

But gson API's are not able to take this date format which I am sending, but taking current date. Whereas if I change getter and setter from Date into String, it works fine.

Comment: More concerning is where strings formatted like that came from. The numeric values before the "+" there actually represent timestamp value in milliseconds since epoch. You would probably be better sorting those out with a regex in your source. Formatted strings like that should not be present in JSON or especially stored in your collection.

Comment: Its date in unix format, I am simply trying to convert it into Java date format using getter and setter but gson is not supporting it. Any solution?

Comment: What I am telling you is that the "numeric" part I mentioned is in Unix format indeed. But the overall string source is garbage. So it's not a great idea to set up a common parser to deal with this, but rather fix it. Where is that data coming from? Is it an external JSON source or is this how it has been stored in MongoDB?

Comment: It is external json source, I am trying to convert it into java date format and then put it in mongodb.

Comment: Only trying to lead you in a positive direction here. Is this an external JSON source from a commercial API ( hard to believe because it's pretty bad ), or does it actually come from someone on your own project team, or at least somewhere where you can discuss? What it looks like it a very poor effort and dumping a JavaScript Date contsructor within a serialized output. That's really bad and not how to do it. You should avoid writing code to work with that and get the source corrected ideally.